# How do you get the array length of a variable in a localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have a array stored in localStorage that has a key named "key" it contains this values ["Gio","Ben"]

how do i get the length 
I've tried

`localStorage.getItem("name").length;`

but it shows a different output
what i was expecting was supposed to be 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse the array using `JSON.parse` and then you can get its length just like any other array.

```
var arrayFromStroage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name"));
var arrayLength = arrayFromStroage.length;
```

---

Just for your awareness, `localStorage.getItem("name").length;` will get you the length of JSON string that you have stored in localStorage. For array `["Gio","Ben"]`, its JSON string is `"["Gio","Ben"]"`. So the length would be 13.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but how about if i wanna get a specific value from the array?

Comment: @Yatoooo Then you can iterate over the parsed array, i.e. `arrayFromStroage` in my snippet. Or, you could even filter over that array.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: sir how do i loop print the contents of the array
I've tried for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
 //print
}
but it prints only the last value of the array which is Ben

Comment: @Yatoooo There are several ways of doing that. First being `for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){ console.log(arrayFromStroage[i]); }` Second is, `arrayFromStorage.forEach(t => console.log(t));`  You should refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3010840/5894241) question for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The `localStorage` only stores Strings.

If you have an Array in there, you need to parse it before using it with `JSON.parse` :

```js
var arrStr = '["Gio","Ben"]';

console.log(JSON.parse(arrStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can only save string value in local Storage. the getItem("name") function return a string. so first you have to convert this into a json object and then you can get array length.

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name")).length;
```

Comment: @Yatoooo try this. hope this will help for you

Answer (score 0):

Actually we have string value in local Storage. the `getItem("name").length` function return total number of characters in a string. So, in case of Lists you can try all of the above mentioned tricks but in case of dictionary they won't work. So, what u can do is just fetch all the keys and then count them.
Here is what you can do:

`Object.keys(name).length;`

it will work.